# Android: Listview with button Delete

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a Listview which should have a button Delete per item. Each item has 3 textViews inside.

The problem is that I'm getting an exception "***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference***"

I know I'm getting this error on **MyAdapter.java** on getView() but I can't fix it, I have no ideas, can you please help me?

getNome(), getQuantia() and getCategoria() are methods from object Despesa.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Despesa> list = new ArrayList<Despesa>();
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }    
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ver__despesas, null);
            }

            //Handle TextView and display string from your list
            TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
            listItemText.setText(list.get(0).getNome());
            TextView listItemText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantia);
            listItemText2.setText(list.get(1).getQuantia());
            TextView listItemText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoria);
            listItemText3.setText(list.get(2).getCategoria());

            //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
            ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ImgButtonDel);
    (...)
}
}
```

**Check_Activity.java**

```
public class Check_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
(...)
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
(...)
 List<Despesa> despesas;
        despesas = databaseHelper.getAllDespesas(mes, ano);

        ArrayList<Despesa>items = new ArrayList<Despesa>();

        for(int i=0;i<despesas.size();i++)
        {

            items.add(new Despesa(despesas.get(i).getNome(),despesas.get(i).getQuantia(), despesas.get(i).getCategoria()));
        }

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(items, this);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
(...)
```

**mes_info.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewNome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewQuantia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMes"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMes"
            android:text="Name: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCategoria"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewAno"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAno"
            android:text="Continent: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImgButtonDel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/trashdelete"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_check.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.android.Ver_DespesasActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCancelar"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first use this list.get(position).getNome()

Comment: In MyAdapter.java you are inflating `activity_ver__despesas`  whereas the textview in the adapter is using the textview in `mes_info.xml`. Change to `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mes_info, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the exception because your views are not found by `findViewByID`. So, it seems that you are inflating the wrong layout:

You are inflating the view from `activity_ver__despesas` layout:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ver__despesas, null);
```

But the layout you posted, which contains `textViewNome`, `textViewQuantia` and `textViewCategoria`, is named `mes_info`.

---

EDIT:

Also, you are getting fields from different items in the list, not the current one, as you invoke `getItem` with hardcoded indexes:

```
//Handle TextView and display string from your list
TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
listItemText.setText(list.get(0).getNome());
TextView listItemText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantia);
listItemText2.setText(list.get(1).getQuantia());
TextView listItemText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoria);
listItemText3.setText(list.get(2).getCategoria());
```

You should do this:

```
<YOUR_ITEMS_CLASS> item = get(position); // Current item

//Handle TextView and display string from your list
TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
listItemText.setText(item .getNome());
TextView listItemText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantia);
listItemText2.setText(item.getQuantia());
TextView listItemText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoria);
listItemText3.setText(item.getCategoria());
```

`getView` receives a parameter for the item `position` whose view is going to be build.

Once it's working you could consider using ViewHolder pattern to improve performance in list scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You adapter's getView method is not correct.

1. Create a Holder class to hold the xml components
2. Please study this getview method and try to implement it to your case:

Example of a correct getView method and holder class :

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Get an instance of our holder
    Holder holder;


    //Check if this is the first time we are creating this row for the listview
    if (row == null){

        //Row was null and thus we need to get components from the row_details.xml
        holder = new Holder();

        //get the Android's layout inflater service which will read our row_details.xml
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Fill our row view with the xml layout file
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_details, null);

        //Fill our holder with the text view components
        holder.textViewName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_details_textview_name);
        holder.textViewId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.row_details_textview_id);

        //This is very imp! attach our holder to the row
        row.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        //row was created before! thus get the holder object from the row tag
        holder = (Holder)row.getTag();
    }


    //At this point we have our row, either created from new or got it from the row tag object
    //we can now fill the data

    //First get our object from the list which is in the position of the listview
    //The position as you can see is passed to the getView method by the listview
    Person person = getItem(position);

    holder.textViewName.setText(person.getFirstname());
    holder.textViewId.setText("ID: " + person.get_id());

    //we are done formatting our row..return to listview to show
    return row;
}

//A holder will be resposable to hold our components to improve listview performance
//We replicate the components we have in the row_details.xml
private class Holder{

    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewId;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MyAdapter.java you are inflating `activity_ver__despesas` whereas the textview in the adapter is using the textview in mes_info.xml. Change to:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mes_info, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `getView` , you inflate the row's view, so change :
`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ver__despesas, null);`
to 
`view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mes_info, null);`

so that `view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);` will return the view you want and not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private ArrayList<Despesa> list = new ArrayList<Despesa>();
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}    
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)      {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mes_info, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(0).getNome());
        TextView listItemText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantia);
        listItemText2.setText(list.get(1).getQuantia());
        TextView listItemText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoria);
        listItemText3.setText(list.get(2).getCategoria());

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ImgButtonDel);
       deleteBtn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code for deleter...
            }
        }
    });
```

}